# How to shorten a sentence which got long due to commas followed by another lines

Tags: sentence-choice

This is a sentence, I've to write in an e-mail

> I have been waiting for any information from the office regarding the cause of delay, but despite multiple follow-ups with ... & writing emails of request, I'm completely uninformed about the status of my scholarship.

How to write this in shorter sentences/sentence as I've heard writing long sentences is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context, I would say the length isn't excessive at the moment - its basically only three phrases.

The most obvious thing you can do is remove `, but` and replace with a full-stop. If this was for an assignment, it might keep the teacher happy, but I think it should be obvious that it doesn't make the paragraph significantly more readable.

Comment: I'm with Mike. But I'd consider rephrasing the note: I am still waiting to hear the outcome of my application for a scholarship. In spite of numerous emails requesting information from the office, I am none the wiser about the cause of the delay.

Comment: @RonaldSole and I'm with both of you  :D